# Indexes or tags? For multiple checkboxes as buttons in IBOutletCollection

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, button, checkbox

I'm kind of new to swift, but someone mentioned that I should use indexes or tags for the buttons in an IBOutletCollection.

Im not sure how to index or tag specific buttons, and then reference them in the cases:

```
// images of checked and unchecked boxes for the button to switch between
var BoxON = UIImage(named: "CheckBox")
var BoxOFF = UIImage(named:"UnCheckBox")

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    boxes.forEach {
        $0.setImage(BoxOFF, for: .normal)
        $0.setImage(BoxON, for: .selected)
    }

}

@IBOutlet var boxes : [UIButton]!

@IBAction func boxTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    let index = boxes.index(of: sender)!
    switch index {

        case 0:
            sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        case 1:
            sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        case 2:
            sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        case 3:
            sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        case 4:
            sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        default:
            sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT:
Removed the switch and replaced with an if statement (It Works!)

```
  @IBAction func boxTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

    if sender.isSelected{

        sender.setImage(BoxOFF, for: .normal)
        sender.setImage(BoxON, for: .selected)

    }
```

Comment: What's the point of your `switch`? Every case does the same thing which actually undoes the change done in the first line of your `boxTouched` function.

Comment: yes! thank you, I've just realized this and solved it by removing the switch and replacing with: 

if sender.isSelected{ 
    sender.setImage(BoxOFF, for: .normal)
    sender.setImage(BoxON, for: .selected)
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On storyboard you can set tag for every button in attribute inspector. [image: In image you can see the selected button and tag property for it in Attributes inspector] Following is the altered code:

```
@IBAction func boxTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {
sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
let buttonTag = sender.tag
switch tag {

    case 0:
        //code you want to write for case 0
    case 1:
        //code you want to write for case 1
    case 2:
        //code you want to write for case 2
    case 3:
        //code you want to write for case 3
    case 4:
        //code you want to write for case 4
    default:
        //code you want to write for default case

}
```

}

Comment: You should probably show how to connect the button to the IBAction.

Answer (score 1):

You click on each button in the storyboard and then set the tag in the Attributes inspector. This is something you should do because IBOutletCollections aren't guaranteed to maintain the order.

[image]

Then in your code you just access the tag like so: sender.tag

```
@IBAction func clickedButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    switch sender.tag {
    case 0:
        print("this is button 0")
    case 1:
        print("this is button 1")
    case 2:
        print("this is button 2")
    default:
        print("unknown button")
    }
}
```

This works for me after <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+dragging each button to the method.

Comment: thank you! so I've changed the tag #'s and changed my switch statement condition to be sender.tag. not really sure why my code won't work

Comment: Make sure you ctrl-click and drag all buttons to the IBAction method as well.

Comment: Have you connected your IBAction correctly?  If you put a breakpoint in your `boxTouched` method, is it getting hit?

Comment: Also, setting a button to be "selected" is probably not doing what you are expecting.  A button being "selected" is making the button the selected button when accessibility functions are turned on to read the button to iOS users who have visual impairment.

Comment: yes ty! my sender.isselected was handling the cases wrong